# Shapes.Visible True and False within Loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this piece of code which I would like to show and hide some Shape objects one by one, in order to make a little animation. However, nothing happens as the code executes, all images are shown by once when the code stops running.

```
Sub test()

    For i = 1 To 4

        Sheets("Game").Shapes("North" & i).Visible = True

        Sleep 500

        'Sheets("Game").Shapes("North" & i).Visible = False
        'by setting it to false i'd like to achieve the animation effect

        Debug.Print i

        DoEvents

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Does moving the `DoEvents` before the `Sleep` call help anything?

Comment: Where are you hiding the shapes? Have you tried `DoEvents` after `Visible = True` and then `DoEvents` after `Visible = False`?

Comment: Setting `DoEvents` after `Visible = True` and then `DoEvents` after `Visible = False` did the trick!

Comment: Cool! I'll explain why in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DoEvents` allows other code (e.g. Excel's own) to run and handle things like user clicking on another worksheet (which invokes any `Worksheet.Change` or `Workbook.WorksheetChange` handler)... or just repainting itself.

By invoking `DoEvents` once per loop, Excel doesn't get a chance to repaint between the visibility toggles: it's already busy running your loop.

So you need to toggle visibility on, let Excel repaint (`DoEvents`), sleep for your animation delay (500ms seems a tad slow IMO), then toggle visibility off *and let Excel repaint again*, i.e. invoke `DoEvents` one more time.

If the `Game` worksheet is in `ThisWorkbook`, then I'd warmly recommend you give it a `CodeName` - select it in the *Project Explorer*, then look at its properties (F4) and change its `(Name)` to, say, `GameSheet`.

This gives you a global-scope object variable so that you don't need to dereference the same worksheet twice per iteration - heck you could even dereference its `Shapes` collection only once:

```
Private Const ANIMATION_DELAY As Long = 100

Sub test()

    With GameSheet.Shapes

        For i = 1 To 4

            Dim currentShape As Shape
            Set currentShape = .Item("North" & i)

            currentShape.Visible = True
            DoEvents

            Sleep ANIMATION_DELAY

            currentShape.Visible = False
            DoEvents

            Debug.Print i

        Next 

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That was amazing. I'll definetely follow your tip of giving the worksheet a `CodeName`!

Answer (score 0):

Amended the code by setting `DoEvents` after toggling `True` and `False`and now it works:

```
Sub test()

    For i = 1 To 4

        Sheets("Game").Shapes("North" & i).Visible = True

        DoEvents

        Sleep 100

        Sheets("Game").Shapes("North" & i).Visible = False

        DoEvents

        'by setting it to false i'd like to achieve the animation effect

        Debug.Print i



    Next i

End Sub
```